# Libgdx collision trouble

Tags: java, android, libgdx, collision-detection

I'm making a top down  RPG. I have almost completed the movement system, but I can't seem to figure out how to detect if the player if a if a tile should block the player. I have two object layers in my tmx file the player should interact with on any map: the NPC layer, and the collision layer. I've tried the NPCs are tile objects (come out as RectangleMapObjects) and are usually 1.5 tiles high, and the collision objects are polygons, also I have some tiles I want to only be accessed from one side as such I need to know if three separate points that depend on direction are within the collision. After several hours this is what I have:

```
public boolean canWalk(float xc, float yc, String dir)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            RectangleMapObject temp = (RectangleMapObject) ents.get(i);
            if (!temp.equals(player))
            {
                if (dir.equals("s"))
                {
                    float cy = ((y) * 16) - 2;
                    float cx = ((x) * 16) + 2;
                    return !(temp.getRectangle().contains(cx + 6, cy + 8));
                }
                else if (dir.equals("n"))
                {
                    float cy = ((y + 1) * 16) + 2;
                    float cx = ((x) * 16) + 2;
                    return !(temp.getRectangle().contains(cx, cy) && temp.getRectangle().contains(cx + 6, cy) && temp.getRectangle().contains(cx + 12, cy));
                }
                else if (dir.equals("e"))
                {
                    float cy = ((y) * 16) + 2;
                    float cx = ((x + 1) * 16) + 2;
                    return !(temp.getRectangle().contains(cx, cy) && temp.getRectangle().contains(cx, cy + 6) && temp.getRectangle().contains(cx, cy + 12));
                }
                else if (dir.equals("w"))
                {
                    float cy = ((y) * 16) + 2;
                    float cx = ((x) * 16) - 2;
                    return !(temp.getRectangle().contains(cx, cy) && temp.getRectangle().contains(cx, cy + 6) && temp.getRectangle().contains(cx, cy + 12));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    versionid = "" + i + ",";
    i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            PolygonMapObject temp = (PolygonMapObject) cols.get(i);
            if (dir.equals("s"))
            {
                float cy = ((y) * 16) - 2;
                float cx = ((x) * 16) + 2;
                return !(temp.getPolygon().contains(cx, cy) && temp.getPolygon().contains(cx + 6, cy) && temp.getPolygon().contains(cx + 12, cy));
            }
            else if (dir.equals("n"))
            {
                float cy = ((y + 1) * 16) + 2;
                float cx = ((x) * 16) + 2;
                return !(temp.getPolygon().contains(cx, cy) && temp.getPolygon().contains(cx + 6, cy) && temp.getPolygon().contains(cx + 12, cy));
            }
            else if (dir.equals("e"))
            {
                float cy = ((y) * 16) + 2;
                float cx = ((x + 1) * 16) + 2;
                return !(temp.getPolygon().contains(cx, cy) && temp.getPolygon().contains(cx, cy + 6) && temp.getPolygon().contains(cx, cy + 12));
            }
            else if (dir.equals("w"))
            {
                float cy = ((y) * 16) + 2;
                float cx = ((x) * 16) - 2;
                return !(temp.getPolygon().contains(cx, cy) && temp.getPolygon().contains(cx, cy + 6) && temp.getPolygon().contains(cx, cy + 12));
            }
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    versionid = versionid + i;
    return true;
}
```

And it always returns true

Solved my own issue stupid mistake every check had a guaranteed return rather than only returning if necessary

Comment: I recommend you to use Box2d for Collision handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out here is the functional code for anyone who wants it

```
public boolean canWalk(String dir)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            RectangleMapObject temp = (RectangleMapObject) ents.get(i);
            if (!temp.equals(player))
            {
                if (dir.equals("s"))
                {
                    float cy = ((y) * 16) - 2;
                    float cx = ((x) * 16) + 2;
                    if (temp.getRectangle().contains(cx + 6, cy + 8))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else if (dir.equals("n"))
                {
                    float cy = ((y + 1) * 16) + 2;
                    float cx = ((x) * 16) + 2;
                    if (temp.getRectangle().contains(cx, cy) && temp.getRectangle().contains(cx + 6, cy) && temp.getRectangle().contains(cx + 12, cy))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else if (dir.equals("e"))
                {
                    float cy = ((y) * 16) + 2;
                    float cx = ((x + 1) * 16) + 2;
                    if (temp.getRectangle().contains(cx, cy) && temp.getRectangle().contains(cx, cy + 6) && temp.getRectangle().contains(cx, cy + 12))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                else if (dir.equals("w"))
                {
                    float cy = ((y) * 16) + 2;
                    float cx = ((x) * 16) - 2;
                    if (temp.getRectangle().contains(cx, cy) && temp.getRectangle().contains(cx, cy + 6) && temp.getRectangle().contains(cx, cy + 12))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            PolygonMapObject temp = (PolygonMapObject) cols.get(i);
            if (dir.equals("s"))
            {
                float cy = ((y) * 16) - 2;
                float cx = ((x) * 16) + 2;
                if (temp.getPolygon().contains(cx, cy) && temp.getPolygon().contains(cx + 6, cy) && temp.getPolygon().contains(cx + 12, cy))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if (dir.equals("n"))
            {
                float cy = ((y + 1) * 16) + 2;
                float cx = ((x) * 16) + 2;
                if (temp.getPolygon().contains(cx, cy) && temp.getPolygon().contains(cx + 6, cy) && temp.getPolygon().contains(cx + 12, cy))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if (dir.equals("e"))
            {
                float cy = ((y) * 16) + 2;
                float cx = ((x + 1) * 16) + 2;
                if (temp.getPolygon().contains(cx, cy) && temp.getPolygon().contains(cx, cy + 6) && temp.getPolygon().contains(cx, cy + 12))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else if (dir.equals("w"))
            {
                float cy = ((y) * 16) + 2;
                float cx = ((x) * 16) - 2;
                if (temp.getPolygon().contains(cx, cy) && temp.getPolygon().contains(cx, cy + 6) && temp.getPolygon().contains(cx, cy + 12))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e)
        {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Just a note I answered this to close it